# Editing the iptables file on Asus firmware

Tags: linux, iptables, firmware

I have downloaded the Asus DSL-n14u firmware, extracted the .trx file and located the iptables file, as linked below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sanz5x2bw0o5xsu/iptables?dl=0

I know the iptables rules that I need to add. However, I am just a little confused about two things:

1) Is it possible to edit this file, add the rules, repackage the .trx file and then reload the firmware on the router?

2) If #1 is possible, where in the file would I add my custom rules?

Thanks, just need a little guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

You linked the executeable, not the "settings"/rules.

You have to edit the script-file, or the configuration-partition which stores the firewall configuration on the device.

Either

- With a built-in (web) tool
- by downloading/exporting the settings, editing, and re-uploading/importing them again
- By adding/editing script files in the device itself, using serial, telnet, or SSH connectivity.
- running the iptables binary manually with the right parameters on the device

Comment: Oh my bad, so I did. Thanks for your detailed explanation despite that, it will definitely help me. Appreciate it.